# Ad Advertisement block after 4 Blocks automatically

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have website vokzo.com. I add apps block and one is advertisment block But Advertisement block only show one time on whole homepage at the top of apps block's.I want Advertisement block insert automatically after 4 apps blocks .Like when I add apps block's from admin panel after complete 4 blocks website should insert advertisement block automatically.I hope everyone will understand .Below is my index.blade.php file code please someone see and help me.Thank's

```
@extends( "layouts.master")

@section('content')

<div class="row">

     <div class="navigation">    @include('web.home.partials.slider')
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="/category/games">
                    <div class="icon" style="background: #F2B258;"><img src="https://static.apkpure.com/mobile/static/imgs/games.png" width="20"></div>
                    <div class="text">Hot Games</div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/category/apps">
                    <div class="icon" style="background: #FA8484;"><img src="https://static.apkpure.com/mobile/static/imgs/apps.png" width="20"></div>
                    <div class="text">Hot Apps</div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/category">
                    <div class="icon" style="background: #5EC9F3"><img src="https://static.apkpure.com/mobile/static/imgs/category.png" width="20"></div>
                    <div class="text">Category</div>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>


   {{-- Advertisement And Apps Block's Start --}}

    {{-- ads start --}}
    @include('common.ads-placement',[ 'identifier' => 'homepage-leaderboard'])
    {{-- ads end --}}
    {{-- Apps Block Start --}}
    @include('web.home.partials.featured-apps')
    {{-- Apps Block End --}}

  {{-- Advertisement And Apps Block's END --}}

</div>

@endsection

@push('javascript')

@endpush
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question, you have a set of main blocks (*$mainBlocks array*)  and a set of ad blocks (*$adBlocks array*) and in the view, you want to repeatedly show 4 main blocks and then, one ad block. Right?

That would be easy: just use a for loop for the main blocks and after each 4 main block, show one ad block. Some thing like this:

```
$adIndex = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($mainBlocks); $i++)
{
    //show a main block: inlcude('SHOW_MAIN_BLOCK', ['block' => $mainBlocks[$i]])
    if ($i > 0 && $i % 4 == 0 && $adIndex < count($adBlocks))
    {
        //show an ad block: inlcude('SHOW_AD_BLOCK', ['block' => $adBlocks[$adIndex]])
        $adIndex++;
    }
}
```

Comment: sir where should I put this code mean which file should I use any Idea?

Comment: It is actually in your view. So, you pass the $mainBlocks and $adBlocks from your controller to your view. Right? (this code doesn't work as it is, it is just to show you the idea of how it works and you should adopt it to your view)